# Will mathematics journals accept a non-novel theorem, but with different approach

Tags: mathematics, publishability

Suppose a researcher comes up with a mathematical theorem, which can be obtained trivially from discovered theorems, but with an approach, that was never used before to describe or prove the theorem.

Then do the journals accept the paper because of the new approach or reject the paper because of no novelty?

Comment: See also the potential duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/111704/is-it-okay-to-include-a-simplified-and-easy-version-of-a-result-already-proved

Comment: What if Alan Turing didn't publish his paper because of the (previously published) Church's Lambda calculus paper for the Entscheidungsproblem? :)

Comment: @Evariste _Utopia!_ Everybody would be using functional languages instead of imperative ones. ... ...maybe.

Comment: Even a new perspective on an existing theorem can be encouraged in some places… For instance, in their latest call for contribution, [JFLA](http://jfla.inria.fr/) writes « _Nous encourageons aussi la soumission de "perles", ces  articles présentant avec élégance un résultat connu sous un angle nouveau._ », so "_We also encourage the submission of "pearls", these articles elegantly presenting a known result from a new angle._"

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is more to mathematics than theorems. Sometimes the *best* part is the  methodology of the proof, especially if it can be used to also solve important problems in the field. If everybody has been thinking in a certain way about a class of problems for a hundred years and you give them a new way to think about it, you have made an important contribution.

So yes, a journal would publish that. But your paper needs to be clear about the novelty and importance of your approach.

My own dissertation had interesting theorems, but was noted for the proof of one of them that was something entirely new and unexpected.

Comment: I largely agree, but, not every proof methodology is interesting. How can the OP determine whether their methodology is interesting?

Comment: @user2768 Why isn't that for the journals rather than the OP to determine?

Comment: @user2768, You can't always know, of course, but you can suspect that it is so if you've looked for similar things without success. People with a lot of experience are more likely to know, of course.

Comment: @BCLC Perusing a result without knowing whether it is publishable is a waste of time, so although it is possible to let journals decide, it is ill-advised.

Comment: @user2768 wait what? I'm not familiar with publishing actually. How will journals know if something is publishable or not if they don't decide if it's publishable or not?

Comment: @user2768 ah wait you mean a journal may publish, but the proof methodology may or may not be interesting?

Comment: @BCLC Journals use reviewers to advise the editors on which papers are worth publishing. So it comes back to Buffy's "People with a lot of experience" - i.e. the reviewers.

Comment: Think about an extreme case: Let's say you find a simple proof of Fermat's theorem. I'm sure any mathematics journal would be elated to publish that.

Comment: @user2768, wait what??  Pursuing knowledge without knowing whether *someone else* will agree it should be published is a *waste of time*??  And scientific love of inquiry and knowledge just goes out the window into the garbage dump, does it?  What a sad commentary on the state of academia.

Comment: @Wildcard: Given the choice between pursuing knowledge that can be widely shared and pursuing knowledge that no one is interested in, I don't know how you can argue for the latter. (This even without considering practical things like career-building.)

Comment: @ruakh, well, certainly.  But by definition if *you're* interested in it, it's not the case that no one is interested.  Even more to the point, you're equating scientific journal publishing standards with the ability to widely share the knowledge, and equating both with "everyone's" interest level.  I refer you to [an alternative view on the matter](http://markburgess.org/blog_peer.html) (note it's from someone who resigned a full tenured professorship, so it's not sour grapes of inability to attain academic success).

Comment: @Wildcard You seem to dramatize my words words out of context, but let me try to respond: In this instance, it is unclear whether *knowledge* (for wider society) or a *learning exercise* (for the individual) is being pursued. The latter is an interesting pursuit, but it isn't an expected public deliverable of researchers. (I agree that peer review is broken. So are many systems. We work with what we have.)

Answer (score 19):

Edward Witten not only published a paper of this kind (entitled 'A New Proof of the Positive Energy Theorem'), but the paper strongly contributed to getting him a Fields Medal, the highest award in mathematics.  Both proofs in the paper had already been proved by Schoen and Yau using different methods: the key is that he was using new methods to carry out the proof.

Edit: I should also add that general mathematics journals often like to take interesting or easier new proofs of old theorems.

Later: I have thought about this a bit more and the truth is not as quite as glib as I suggested.  Unfortunately these things are never black and white.  The proof by Witten of that theorem was new but also interesting and surprising.  Producing yet another proof of some workhorse theorem which people use on a daily basis might be a bit hard to publish (and I'm speaking from experience as well).

Answer (score 1):

In my area, proving Schur positivity is a big thing. 
One can do that using RSK, bijections, involutions, crystals, dual equivalence, or representation theory.

Some proofs give more insight than others, so there are several different proofs of the same statement, as the different techniques have different pros and cons.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which was about what journals will accept.

Comment: Journals accept this - today I saw 'prominent researcher' put a new preprint on arxiv, reproving a theorem related to positivity using crystals, rather than dual equivalence. I have a (published) conjecture on how to prove the same thing using RSK.